# Using for loop in PANDAS

Tags: python, pandas

Replace the missing values in 'track', 'artist', and 'genre' with the string 'unknown'. To do this, create the columns_to_replace list, loop over it with for, and replace the missing values in each of the columns:

This is my code....please help! I am not sure if I should use `isna()` or `replace()`

```
columns_to_replace = ['track','artist','genre']

for values in columns_to_replace:
    values.replace('unkown')

print (values)
```

Comment: You're not referencing your dataframe at all, assuming that's what you really have.  Your description is too vague.

Comment: Suggest using `.fillna('unknown')`

Comment: `for x in col_to_rep: df[x] = df[x].fillna('unknown')`

Comment: Where's your data frame? `values` is a string, so calling `replace` on it won't work.

Answer (score 1):

I see what you're saying. I don't think this is too vague of a question Mr. Roberts.

So you always want to try **not** iterate through a pandas dataframe when possible. That's because there's probably a function out there that will get the job done for you that way more efficient.

This is what you want to do:

```
df['your column']= df['your column'].fillna('unknown')
```

Repeat the above code for each column. Or you could enter multiple column names in the brackets.

Cheers!

Comment: Or all at once: `df[columns_to_replace] = df[columns_to_replace].fillna('unknown')`